# Visual 2008 Report Server - Parameter Attribute adjustments

Tags: visual-studio, t-sql, reporting, reportserver

I've  been trying trying to adjust the width of the VS 2008 Report Server user parameter text box at runtime to expand or grow or at least wrap somewhat long text.

I've been looking into manually doing so in the web code for the parameter sections but haven't figured it out yet. Any suggestions?

Its said there are options in the designer view but the size attributes do not directly affect this at runtime. It has a scrollbar but is short and that is and seems inefficient for users who will run these reports.

Heres the XML portion I thought I could manually change.

```
 <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="ProjectTypeIDs">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>Project Type</Prompt>
      <ValidValues>
        <DataSetReference>
          <DataSetName>ProjectTypes</DataSetName>
          <ValueField>ProjectTypeID</ValueField>
          <LabelField>ProjectTypeName</LabelField>
        </DataSetReference>
      </ValidValues>
      <MultiValue>true</MultiValue>
    </ReportParameter>
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Your only real option is to provide your own parameter page. It could either be a simple page written specifically for the reports you're publishing which takes the parameter values and passes them to SSRS via a report URL or you could go all out and use the reports web service to retrieve a list of parameters and render them dynamically.

Comment: Thats an idea..thanks for that. I'll either try that or some CSS maybe?. Thanks again -JC